# Rails 3.1.1 - Asset Pipeline - asset.prefix not working with resource :assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am having an issue with the asset pipeline, I already have a resource / controller called assets. So i have changed assets.prefix option to "/externals".

```
config.assets.prefix = '/externals'
```

This simple dose not work unless i remove:

```
resources: assets
```

Then all works as expected.

I am not sure how to write a test to prove this but i have created a app to showcase it.

https://github.com/nodrog/asset-pipeline-issue

If you run the app, and visit '/products' all will work, then go to the routes file and change the variable create_bug to true.

We have looked into https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb, and then added a debugger to the asset_path method.

This method is not called, if you but a debugger in the javascript_include_tag method. And run method(:asset_path).source_location, it tells you it is calling the method from default routes not from the sprockets helper.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: opened a ticket in rails lighthouse on this issue. and have uploaded a folk that fixes the issue, though probably not in the best way. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3643#issuecomment-2775938

Comment: You are right nodrog, this is a complicated issue. I ran into it because the helpers weren't using the config.assets.prefix option at all (whether or not there was resources :assets in routes.rb), and when that was fixed, I figured all was well. Alas, Sprockets helpers don't use the config setting when assets are specified in config.rb. Why?

I'll take a look at your work around now. I've tried working around it with constraints, as well as directing my custom prefix to Sprockets, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

I reported this to the rails people, and they fixed it. The fix is now in the master branch.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3643#issuecomment-2775938